# Retrieve corresponding foreign key with drop-down list (WCF) C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, visual-studio-2015, combobox

I'm using WCF services to load my database table to the drop-down list (combobox). How do I retrieve the selected value into a corresponding value in the table, so when I select an item, the corresponding `int` will be inserted to the table?

Here is my code for the desktop layer:

```
   private void Save()
    {
        if (ValidateForm())
        {
            try
            {
                IHotRes res = new MHotServiceProvider().Service;
                Customer customer = res.SaveCustomer(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, dtpDOB.Value, txtAddress.Text, txtPostCode.Text, txtPhone1.Text, txtPhone2.Text, txtEmailAddress.Text, ddlGender.SelectedIndex); // all other work just don't know how to get the ddlGender

                MessageBox.Show("Data has been inserted to the table");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageHelper.ShowErrorMessage(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need any more information or code sample please comment below. (Maybe the procedure needs editing if so please let me know I will add procedure code).

EDIT: This is how I fill the ddlGender:

```
IHotRes res = new MHotServiceProvider().Service;
List<Genders> gender = res.GetGenderList();
ddlGender.ValueMember = "GenderId";
ddlGender.DisplayMember = "Gender";
ddlGender.DataSource = gender;
```

Comment: How do you fill ddlGender?

Comment: @Sefa I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using

```
ddlGender.ValueMember = "GenderId";
```

Calling SelectedValue property gives you selected genders Id.

In my code below, i assumed GenderId is int. If not, change the type accordingly.

```
Customer customer = res.SaveCustomer(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, dtpDOB.Value, txtAddress.Text, txtPostCode.Text, txtPhone1.Text, txtPhone2.Text, txtEmailAddress.Text, (int)ddlGender.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: sorry you are right thank you (forgot to change `SelectedIndex` to `selectedValue`)